# Signalr:'default' done for a hub.server.method call

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a hub server method called with signalr many times. 
I know i can do:

```
hub.server.method().done(function(data){ 
    //my_code
}
```

but is there any way I can set a 'default' done() function so I don't have to repeat it every time I call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in your *.js file like this

```
function doSomething(){
hub.server.method().done(function(data){ 
    //my_code
}
};
```

And then call doSomething instead of

```
hub.server.method().done(function(data){ 
    //my_code
}
```

**Edited:**

If you want to add a function to the server object you can do:

```
 hub.server.myDecoratedBehavior= function() {
        if (connected) {
            this.originalBehavior().done(function () {
                console.log("Chat window was cleared");
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, this can be fair enough. I can create an object that will act as service for my requests. But can I modify prototype just for one hub to force a 'done' for every request?

Comment: Sure you can. The proxy object (server) is just another javascript object.

Comment: I can't find which object I have to prototype to redefine done() for a specific hub. Do you happen to know which object is?
hub.server.method.prototype.done isn't working as calling a method seems to return a different object

Comment: Please see my updated answer, don't use hub.server.prototype because it is undefined.

Comment: I like it! I'm going to test it, but I think it's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var onDone = function(data) {
  // code
};

hub.server.method1().done(onDone);
hub.server.method2().done(onDone);
```